# Solving simultaneous equations for Weibull distribution parameter estimation

Tags: statistics, summation, matlab, systems-of-equations

What is the best way to solve the equations below using Matlab. I have the values for i, Ni, k, T and am in need of values for rho, beta and alpha.

i goes up to 12

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way would probably be to use [fsolve](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html); in fact, the default algorithm used by fsolve is the trust-region dogleg method (which is the suggested method in the problem statement).

To get started, you reformulate your problem as a nonlinear root finding problem:

$$\textbf{F}(\textbf{x}) = \textbf{0}$$

where

\begin{equation}
\textbf{x} = \begin{bmatrix} \rho \\ \alpha \\ \beta \end{bmatrix} \text{ and } \textbf{F}(\textbf{x}) = \begin{bmatrix} \rho - \text{ RHS of eqn (14)} \\ \text{LHS of eqn (15)} \\ \text{LHS of eqn (16)} \end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}

The goal now is to find $\textbf{x}$ such that $\textbf{F}(\textbf{x}) = \textbf{0}$; if you compare this to the original problem, you will see that these two problems are equivalent.

Next you create a .m file (say "myfun.m") which is a function: input is a vector x = [rho, alpha, beta]; output is F = $\textbf{F}$ evaluated at x. Then you use the command

```
x = fsolve(@myfun,x0);
```

where `x0` is an initial guess to the solution (ideally you would have some intuition as to what might be a good initial guess, but if not then you could choose `x0 = [0, 0, 0]`, `x0 = [1, 1, 1]`, or even `x0 = rand(1, 3)`).

Some useful links from the MATLAB documentation are:

- [the `fsolve` documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html)
- ["When the Solver Fails"](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/when-the-solver-fails.html)
- ["When the Solver Might Have Succeeded"](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/when-the-solver-might-have-succeeded.html)